# AWS authentication/authorization model for new machine2machine API

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, auth0

I am building a REST API that is going to be consumable by paying customers and invoked directly from their backends (no UI).  This fits under the typical user key + secret paradigm offered by API providers such as Stripe.  I am already using AWS for other products and I was hoping to build this API also using AWS cloud services.  After reading on AWS authentication and authorization services it seems like the typical combo is:  Cognito + API Gateway + Lambda.  My problem is that my impression so far is that Cognito solves more the typical Authentication flows associated with a traditional B2C application where a user registers and then authenticates via a typical username+pwd page.  In my case I will be providing my customers with a key+secret that they could use to invoke my API directly from their backend (actually, in a very similar way that AWS does with its SDK users).
My question is whether AWS Cognito is the right tool for this kind of scenario and if so can someone point me in the right direction in terms of links, examples, etc. (I have done many hours of googling myself without success to something equivalent to what I want)?
As a side note, I also started looking into Auth0 which seems to have a solution for this scenario (using an option called Client Credential Grants) but my preference still remains AWS services to facilitate integration and keep the solution the simplest possible all within the same ecosystem.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/sell-api-as-saas-on-aws-marketplace.html.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, although it seems interesting I want more control over my customers' billing and this is not something that is going to be offered publicly to anyone that wants to purchase it, it is more my employer that negotiates specific contracts with corporate customers and then we setup an account for them, we want to be able to give them more than one key+secret pair if need be with different accesses, etc.  The billing rules can be fairly complex and differ from one customer to another.